# Segmentation fault when accessing the text of QLabel

Tags: qt, qlabel

I got a problem with the QLabel. I got a QtWidget with a QLabel inside. Now I want to change the text of the Label with following code:

```
QLabel* safetyLabel = this->findChild<QLabel *>("safety_bits");

safetyLabel->setText(QString("test"));
printf("%i", (safetyLabel->text()).length());
```

but I always get a "Segmentation fault". I think it's something quite simple, but I just can't see it...

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check if `safetyLabel` is `nullptr`?  `findChild` will return one if "safety_bits" could not be found.

Comment: lol you area right, it is a nullptr, seems like I messed something up. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Your `safetyLabel` can be `NULL` if you use QtCreators' designer to build your UI and execute your code before you call `ui->setupUi(this);` in `MainWindow`s constructor.

Comment: Or it could be null for a variety of other reasons. Definitely check that a pointer is non-null before dereferencing!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.

```
QLabel *safetyLabel = NULL;
safetyLabel = (QLabel *) this->findChild("safety_bits");
if(!safetyLabel)
{
    qDebug() << "Failed to find safety_bits label!";
    return 1;
}
safetyLabel->setText(QString("safety_bits is here"));
```