# Promoted CustomQScrollArea segmentation fault

Tags: qt

My actual use case is nontrivial, so I provide a small example that reproduces the segmentation fault:

I have class CustomScrollArea that inherits QScrollArea:

*customscrollarea.h*

```
class CustomScrollArea : public QScrollArea
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit WarxingScrollArea(QWidget* parent=0);
    void segFaultThrowingMethod();
private:
    QLabel* dynamicallyCreatedLabel;
};
```

*customscrollarea.cpp*

```
CustomScrollArea::CustomScrollArea(QWidget* parent) : QScrollArea(parent)
{
    dynamicallyCreatedLabel = new QLabel;
    setWidget(dynamicallyCreatedLabel);

    //this call will _not_ cause a seg fault
    segFaultThrowingMethod();
}

void CustomScrollArea::segFaultThrowingMethod()
{
    dynamicallyCreatedLabel->setText("Some text");
}
```

I have a MainWindow class with the following source:

*mainwindow.h*

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //this call will cause a seg fault
    ui->customScrollArea->segFaultThrowingMethod();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

The .ui file for MainWindow contains a single QScrollArea promoted to a CustomQScrollArea. Its name is “customScrollArea”.

When I start the application, the first invocation of CustomScrollArea::segFaultThrowingMethod() occurs in CustomScrollArea’s constructor for Ui::MainWindow::customScrollArea and passes without incident. However, when MainWindow invokes ui->customScrollArea->segFaultThrowingMethod(), a segmentation fault occurs.

Note that the segmentation fault is not due to CustomScrollArea::dynamicallyCreatedLabel being null (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909809/segmentation-fault-when-accessing-the-text-of-qlabel)). The best clue I have is that this issue does not happen if MainWindow dynamically instantiates a CustomScrollArea rather than getting it from Ui::MainWindow. However, I would like to be able to use QScrollAreas promoted to CustomScrollAreas in Qt Designer.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: did you try to use a debugger? your developing environment?

Comment: Qt Creator on Windows using VC2010.  The debugger indicated dynamicallyCreatedLabel to be the same non-null value in both invocations of segFaultThrowingMethod().  From Pavel's answer, the actual null pointer must have been somewhere deeper in the Qt architecture.  There must be some discrepancy between my compiler and the one that built these Qt libraries, because I was not able to step into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Designer automatically creates an internal widget for any scroll area. This widget is by default called "scrollAreaWidgetContents" and is visible in the Qt Designer's widgets tree. `Ui::MainWindow` class generated by Designer creates a CustomScrollArea for you and performs `setWidget` to set its contents. This action happens in `setupUi` after calling CustomScrollArea constructor. But QScrollArea takes ownership of its internal widget. When `setWidget` is called, the previous scroll area's internal widget (if any) is dismissed and destroyed. So calling `setWidget` inside `setupUi` causes destruction of previously created QLabel, and `dynamicallyCreatedLabel` pointer becomes invalid.

There is no way to delete "scrollAreaWidgetContents" in Qt Designer. The workaround is to add a Widget to the form and promote it to CustomScrollArea class. Qt Designer will not know that CustomScrollArea is actually a QScrollArea and will not call `setWidget` itself. The only side effect is that you will not be able to set scroll area specific properties and access its slots in Qt Designer. But you can do that from your code, so it's not a big problem.

Comment: That workaround worked; thanks!  I suppose another solution would be to postpone dynamicallyGeneratedLabel's creation until after CustomScrollArea's constructor.